# Format json in html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json object that I would like to put in may page in as html.

here is the json:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Temoignage",
        "id":"2"
    },
    {
        "name":"Bien etre",
        "id":"3"
    },
    {
        "name":"paradis",
        "id":"5"
    },
    {
        "name":"guerir",
        "id":"6"
    },
    {
        "name":"energie",
        "id":"9"
    }
]
```

I want to use append function to put this in a div tag like :

```
<div id="content">
<p><a href="id"> name </a></p>
<p><a href="id"> name </a></p>
<p><a href="id"> name </a></p>
.
.
.
</div>
```

N.B: id and name are the entries of my json object.

Comment: You should put the json in jsfiddle: noone wants to click on that link, who knows what's behind?

Comment: {"name":"Temoignage","id":"2"},{"name":"Bien etre","id":"3"},{"name":"paradis","id":"5"},{"name":"guerir","id":"6"},{"name":"energie","id":"9"}]

Comment: @frenchie I think that's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your array using `each` and append each item to the `content` div using `appendTo`:

```
var json = [{"name":"Temoignage","id":"2"},{"name":"Bien etre","id":"3"},{"name":"paradis","id":"5"},{"name":"guerir","id":"6"},{"name":"energie","id":"9"}]​;

var $content = $("#content");
$.each(json, function () {
    $("<a>", { href: this.id }).text(this.name).appendTo($content).wrap("<p>");
});
```

​
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KNMFk/)**.

Answer (score 6):

```
var items="";
$.each(data,function(index,item){
    items+="<p><a href='"+item.id+"'>"+item.name+"</a></p>";
});
$("#content").html(items);
```

Assuming data variable will have the `JSON` data.

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/Qq2e6/

[JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a useful tool to validate JSON, when you work with JSON

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could also use one of the many templating libraries out there.

Here's an example using [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bboone/dCVwt/1

**JS**

```
var json = [{"name":"Temoignage","id":"2"},{"name":"Bien etre","id":"3"},{"name":"paradis","id":"5"},{"name":"guerir","id":"6"},{"name":"energie","id":"9"}]; 

$('#content').html(Mustache.render($('#template').html(), {items:json}));
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='content'></div>
<script type='text/html' id='template'>
    {{#items}}
        <p><a href="{{id}}">{{name}}</a></p>
    {{/items}}
</script>​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsArray; // Your JSON content into this variable

$.each(jsArray, function(i,e) {
   var $element = $("<p>").append($("<a>").attr('id', e.id).text(e.name)),
   $("#content").append($element);
});

<div id="content">

</div>
```

Alternatively, I'd advise you learning MVVM (Knockout.js) for something like this, it separates your layers and makes this process easier.